# Use data from variable in bash

Tags: bash, azure, shell

This is what I am trying to do in bash. Here is a PowerShell example:

`$metaData = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -URI http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2019-04-30 -Method GET`
`$azEnv = $metadata.compute.azEnvironment`

The above command gives me the value of azEnviroment from the Json output and saves that as a variable called $azEnv.

How can I do this in bash?

Comment: You need external utilities, particularly `curl` and `jq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
PC_VMSIZE=$(curl -s -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2018-10-01" | jq -r '.compute.vmSize')
export AZHPC_VMSIZE=${AZHPC_VMSIZE,,}
#echo "Running on $PC_VMSIZE"
```

Comment: Thanks alot! for whatever reason I could not remember "jq". Brain was stuck in PowerShell since I was just using it.Thanks a lot, saved me lots of time!